Copying value from one Filed to Another while UpSerting in MongoDB
I have a model called myModel in my project as below:
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class myModel
{
    [Required]
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("wac")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
    public decimal? Wac { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("previousWac")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
    public decimal? PreviousWac { get; set; }
}

I'm trying do Upsert here. Also, while doing Upsert, I want to do as below:
Copy existing "Wac" to "PreviousWac" and Add new Value to "Wac"
var filter = Builders<myModel>.Filter.Eq("_id", item.id);
var updateDefinition = new BsonDocument("$set", new BsonDocument
{
    ["previousWacPerUnit"] = new BsonDocument("$toDecimal", "$wacPerUnit"), // This approach is incorrect for field copying
    ["wacPerUnit"] = new BsonDecimal128(newValueGoesHere),
});

But what I observed that is, It has created a new field called "WacPerUnit" in PascalCase and previousWacPerUnit is not updated.
Could someone please help me on this?

A basic MongoDB update query is not able to update the field with another field value. You need the Aggregation Pipeline in the update query.
In MongoDB query:
db.collection.update(
  { _id: /* Document id */ },
  { 
    $set: {
      PreviousWac: { $toDecimal: "$Wac" },
      Wac: /* newValueGoesHere */
    }
  },
  { isUpsert: true }
)

var filter = Builders<myModel>.Filter.Eq("_id", item.id);

var updatePipelineDefinition = Builders<myModel>.Update.Pipeline(
    new BsonDocument[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$set", 
            new BsonDocument
            {
                ["PreviousWac"] = new BsonDocument("$toDecimal", "$Wac"),
                ["Wac"] = new BsonDecimal128(newValueGoesHere),
            })
    });

var updateResult = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, updatePipelineDefinition, new UpdateOptions
{
    IsUpsert = true
});

